# Pillow, PDF and 1-bit pixels

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create a PDF of a complicated black-and-white rectangular grid, nominally 7 inches wide by 10 inches tall.  I'm using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/) to do the conversion.  If I specify a PNG, everything works fine (that is, the aspect ratio is 7 by 10).  If I specify a PDF, the output is 200 inches wide and 0.04 inches tall.  What's going on?

Incidentally, if I set `mode='RGB'`, then the output PDF dimensions are correct, but Pillow performs a JPEG encoding of the image. JPEG converts my sharp black and white grid into smoother shades of gray (which is anathema for my application).

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image

# Let's consider a 7" x 10" rectangle of pixels
inches_wide=7
inches_tall=10
dpi=200
num_pixel_rows=inches_tall*dpi
num_pixel_cols=inches_wide*dpi

# Make an image
mode='1'
img = Image.new( mode, (num_pixel_cols,num_pixel_rows))
img.info['dpi'] = (dpi,dpi)

# Saving it as PNG, we get a black rectangle, as expected.
img.save('big_rectangle.png','png',resolution=dpi)
# Saving it as a PDF, we get a 200" x 0.04" all-white line?!
img.save('big_rectangle.pdf','pdf',resolution=dpi)

# Versioning info:
print 'PILLOW',PIL.PILLOW_VERSION
print 'PIL',PIL.VERSION
#  My output:
#  PILLOW 3.1.1
#  PIL 1.1.7
```